# python argparser, argument executing function

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I was wondering how coul i execute a function in python with just a call of an argument when running that command, for example,

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Database accounts manager")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--show", help="Shows all database rows and columns", dest="show",required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.show:
     print("i am beautiful")
```

> what i would like is to when i call this file :  python file.py -s or python file.py --show, i would like it to execute a function like i wrote for an example : "print("i am beautiful")

because when i do that i need to give an argument so it executes the function: "print(...)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add action to the parameters:

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "--show", help="Shows all database rows and columns", dest="show",required=False, action="store_true")
```

Comment: i was thinking and i'm going to try to do "nargs=0"  let's see
but what is that action parameter for?, because i dont want to store any value since im not gonna give any value u understand?, could i use action to execute a function? insteaed of "store_true" can i pass like "funcshow" =??

Comment: oh ok. so i tried nargs=0 and it says i should use actions but since i don't want to store any value what should i use then=?

Comment: i used what u wrote up there and it works now so thanks a lot bro :D
im dumb as hell ahhahah